# How to use the cor() function to calculate the combined correlation of two variables with a third variable?

Tags: r, correlation

I want to calculate the combined correlation of two variables 'age' and 'smoke' with the the response variable 'bwt'. The data - 'birthwt' is from the MASS library.

Here's the code for correlation between twovariables

```
library(MASS)
data(birthwt)
cor(birthwt$bwt,birthwt$age)
```

Why we cannot use the below to find the combined correlation?

```
cor(birthwt$bwt,birthwt$age + birthwt$smoke)
```

Comment: What do you mean `combined correlation`? This is the first time I hear of this.

Comment: it's more like this a~b+c. correlation of 'b' and 'c' to 'a' are not independent to each other.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for a correlation matrix? `cor(birthwt[,c("bwt","age","smoke")])`

Comment: it'll only give correlation between a&b and a&c.

Comment: Your code should work then, you can add two variables to get a new third aggregated variable. Although I don't know if this makes sense.